# boost::regex_match gives different result than many online reggex tester

Tags: c++, regex, boost, boost-regex

I want to match a string given in an input field.

```
A sample data could be "hello" -> returns true 
or "\"" -> returns true 
or "this is a string" -> returns true 
but """ should not be recognized as a string and should return false when checked by the regexp.
```

I am initializing a boost regex parser as follow:

```
    std::string myString = "\"\"\"";
    boost::smatch match;
    boost::regex regExpString3("[\"']((:?[^\"']|\\\")+?)[\"']");
    bool statusString3 = boost::regex_match(myString, match, regExpString3);
```

The regex_match should not match but unfortunately it does match ...

I checked on several online reggex tester: my regular expression did not match (as expected).

Any idea if this could be a bug of boost or am I doing something wrong ?

[Debuggex Demo: Click me to verify ("[\"']((:?[^\"']|\\")+?)[\"']"](https://www.debuggex.com/r/x7PPH1YzPf1uwUgo)

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to match, can you show us some sample data with expected output ?

Comment: Hi Sniffer, I want to match a string given in an input field. A sample data could be "hello" -> returns true  or "\"" -> returns true or "this is a string" -> returns true but """ should not be recognized as a string and should return false when checked by the regexp.

Comment: Please edit your question to include this information.

Comment: Write an online regex tester based on boost, and there will be an online tester what match! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following expression:

```
([\\"'])(?:[^\\"]|\\\\")+\\1
```

[Regex101 Demo](http://regex101.com/r/dQ0zF1)

Comment: `regex_match` matches the entire string, so the leading `^` and the trailing `$` are not needed.

Comment: @PeteBecker Thank you, I don't work with boost nor `regex_match` so I didn't know that, I will edit accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

A regular expression is overkill for this simple check. Just check the string for an opening quotation mark, then search for the next quotation mark that isn't precede by a backslash. If that second quotation mark isn't at the end, the string isn't in the correct format.

Comment: Sorry I had posted a wrong comment I deleted. Good point I will check this as soon as I find some tile to compare the benefit of your solution.